# How to sort an IntNode list

Tags: c#

```
class IntNode
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public IntNode next { get; set; }

        public IntNode(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public IntNode(int value, IntNode next)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public bool HasNext ()
        {
            return (this.next != null);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (this.HasNext())
                return this.value + " --> " + this.next;
            else
                return this.value + ". [end]";
        }
    }
```

If I am getting the first node of a list, how can I sort the list from smallest to highest?

**Example:**

for the list

> 5,-4,8,12,5,71,13,0

that list will be returned

> -4,0,5,5,8,12,13,71

I have tried to do it but I can`t figure it out... Thanks!

What I have tried:

```
static IntNode Sort (IntNode head)
        {
            IntNode pos = head.next;
            IntNode max = head;
            IntNode current = head;

            while (current != null)
            {
                while (pos != null)
                {
                    if (pos.value > max.value) max = pos;
                    pos = pos.next;
                }
                head.next = max.next;
                max.next = head;
                head = max;
                pos = current;
                max = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            return head;
        }
```

this is my homeword so pls help.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, i.e. the code that you tried for sorting?  Are you using a particular sorting algorithm?  You should google it...they're pretty common and easy to implement.

Comment: You'd probably need to implement `IComparable` to sort it

Comment: @rory.ap My tries are very far from the final product and very complicated and long... I rather to get an answer here...

Comment: Your tries are very complicated?  **Show us what you've tried and we'll help**.  We won't write the code for you; we'll help you get your own code working.  I'll reverse my downvote once you've edited the question with the code you need assistance with.

Comment: Okay well, sorting a list of numbers is definitely not a novel idea...it's been covered thoroughly since time immemorial.  And it's fairly simple, like I said..it really only takes 5 or 10 lines of code.  Just google it.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Amy I edited my post.

Comment: Okay.  I've reversed my downvote as promised.

Comment: I assume this is homework? Could you mention that in your post? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: It is homework, but what is it matters? I will mantion

Comment: are you able to write down in normal language how you imagine the sorting algorithm is supposed to work?

Comment: I have given an example. Look at my try it should be something simple with not too advanced syntax

Comment: I tried your example it removes half of the values that you want to sort. The description of the algorithm is supposed to help you to find your error in the sorting algorithm. Sometimes it becomes clearer and obvious to one self if you try to explain it to others.

Comment: @MongZhu I don`t know what I should fix in my program. Can you create an answer with similar code that works?

Comment: I can, actually I already did. But I am trying to get you to a learning process that you can benefit of. Don't you want to learn fishing? or are you only interested in single fish?

Comment: @MongZhu didn`t realized u... :\
pls send me answer I am sitting on this question something like a day

Comment: @OhayonDaniel I wrote my answer. It has the entire algorithm but not the entire code. If you still have difficulties to get it right, drop me a comment.

Comment: @OhayonDaniel did you figure it out? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be clear about your idea of how the algorithm for sorting is supposed to work. It helps to write it down in normal language.

From your code I see that you wander through your list and try to compare the current item with the next. That sounds like the right approach. The condition is right but the moving of values does not work in you solution.

```
if (pos.value > max.value)
```

The basic idea of sorting is moving the items. 
In other words :

**while** it is **not sorted** yet and **while** the **next** element is **not null** and **if** the **current** item is larger than the **next** exchange the **values** then move to the **next** element and do it again.

```
// in the beginning you only need one helping IntNode variable
IntNode current = head;
// and a flag to stop the sorting
bool sorted = false;
```

I would suggest to switch the values

```
//    the condition for the comparison
if (current.value > current.next.value)
{
    int temp = current.value;
    current.value = current.next.value;
    current.next.value = temp;
    // set the flag the a sort procedure has been made as indicator that it might still not be sorted
    sorted = false;
}
```

The rest are 2 while-loops and a boolean variable to stop the outer loop.

**EDIT:**

Since you seem to have figured it out on your own, for the sake of completeness here is my version of the sorting method:

```
public static IntNode Sort(IntNode head)
{
    IntNode current = head;
    bool sorted = false;

    while (!sorted)
    {
        // assume that at this run you actually finished your sorting job
        sorted = true;
        // set the current element to the first position
        current = head;

        while (current.next != null)
        {
            if (current.value > current.next.value)
            {
                int temp = current.value;
                current.value = current.next.value;
                current.next.value = temp;
                // apparently you found an element that was not sorted, so you might not be done yet
                sorted = false;
            }
            // move one element forward
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: @OhayonDaniel Glad to hear that you figured it out. Congratulation! :) I posted my version for the sake of completeness. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface on your class.

```
class IntNode : IComparable {
    // ...

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        IntNode otherNode = obj as IntNode ;
        if (otherNode != null) 
            return this.value.CompareTo(otherNode.value);
        else
           throw new ArgumentException("Object is not an IntNode");
    }
}
```

Put all your nodes into a list, then use the [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var allNodes = new List<IntNode>();
// add nodes to list ...
allNodes.Sort();
```

Comment: That is not the way I wanted to do this... Look at my try

Comment: I get the impression this is for a class and he's supposed to implement his own sorting algorithm.

Comment: You are probably right Amy. Still, I would recommend to implement `IComparable` and then use it in the custom sorting algorithm. This hides how the comparison is made inside the object. The algorithm can then operate on an `IEnumerable<IComparable>` which is a nice abstraction.